# Is it possible to detect gcc compilation flag on compile time as Macros?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to check if compilation flag is set on compile time as preprocessor directive under gcc? More precisely I want to detect if `-rdynamic` linker flag is set?

Comment: Why do you ask? What for?

Comment: Please edit your question to explain more.

Answer (score 4):

`-rdynamic` is not a *compiler* flag, but a [*linker* one](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html). Recall that `gcc`is only a driver program, which starts the compiler proper `cc1`, the assembler `as`, the linker `ld` etc... Try passing `-v` to `gcc` to understand what it is starting.

I would suggest that you conventionally pass some appriate preprocessor `-Dwith_rdynamic` to the compiler when passing `-rdynamic`. This is often a matter of `make` (i.e. code some good `Makefile` ...)

You probably could use `nm -D` on the produced executable to check that it was linked with `-rdynamic`. Or you could use (inside your program) [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) with a `NULL` path, and then `dlsym(3)` some symbol, etc.

I can't figure out why you really need to check `-rdynamic`: when it is needed, you notice very quickly that you missed it!

Comment: There is a library I wrote. I need to warn anyone who use it whenever they forget to miss to include -rdynamic on compile time.

Comment: Please edit your question to explain more. Why would the user of your library be unhappy if missing `-rdynamic`? Explain exactly why (by editing and improving your question) please!

Answer (score 1):

Although I cannot state absolutely no, I expect not.

Use the following command to see predefined macros supported by the gcc and g++ compilers

- gcc   -dM -E -x c /dev/null
- g++   -dM -E -x c++ /dev/null

This might also be of help.

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/